# How do I associate a uploaded file to the user?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I use signed url and upload file from client side.

When a user of my application uploaded a file to cloud storage using signed url from client side. The client side code like this:

```js
          upload(signedUrl, file) {
            return fetch(signedUrl, {
              method: 'PUT',
              body: file
            }).then((res) => {
              console.log('upload success');
              console.log('res: ', res);
            });
          },
```

It will trigger a cloud function to validate the uploaded file.

How do I know the user id in cloud function?

Because I want to publish a `validationPassed` message with user id and gcs object name to notify my backend server to save this gcs object name to database by user id.

Comment: Hi @slideshowp2 Can you accept Doug Stevenson answer? It will make it more visible and help someone with the same issue as you find the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no sort of user identity associated with the file when uploaded like that through the REST API.  You could try to set metadata along with the upload, but that is not secure, and anyone could pass any ID (or pass no ID).

The only secure way that I know to upload a file and get a secure user is to upload with the Firebase client library while also using Firebase Authentication, putting the UID in metadata or the file path, then using security rules to check that the actual UID matches the stated UID.

Comment: OK. Thanks. But I am using cloud storage, not firebase. How can I do this? What if I validate the user id in my cloud function? Is it secure enough?

Comment: I understand that you're using Cloud Storage.  Firebase provides an SDK to upload directly from web clients to a storage bucket.  As I said, that is the only way that I know of to upload to Cloud Storage while securely providing a UID.

Comment: How do I set metadata along with the upload using `PUT` request? Is there any docs about this? Thanks.

Comment: First please read the documentation for the JSON API that you're using, then post a separate question if you're still having trouble. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/